# XAML Horizontal Scrolling With two items

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I'm having some issues getting the horizontal scrolling on the itemspage work.

The default grid template will scroll horizontally if it has more data and the screen adjusts to it. But I want to add a listview to the page as well.

So basically, I want the page to be horizontally scrolled with the grid, then scroll to the list.

At present, it just partially cuts off the "MessageList".

See XAML Below:

```
    <common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>

    <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"/>
</common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,0.429,0.429">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

            <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemGridView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Padding">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="96,136,86,56"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <!--
                The back button and title have different styles when snapped, and the list representation is substituted
                for the grid displayed in all other view states
            -->
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemListView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemGridView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,136,116,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

    <ListView x:Name="MessageList" Height="628" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1191,0,-219,0"  
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplate}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="399"/>

    <!-- Vertical scrolling list only used when snapped -->
    <ListView
        x:Name="itemListView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        Margin="0,-10,0,0"
        Padding="10,0,0,60"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard80ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"/>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your `GridView`, `ListView` and `ListView` in a `ScrollViewer`, and set the following properties:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
<!-- The elements you want to be horizontally scrollable goes here -->
</ScrollViewer>
```